# RegEx returns empty string

Tags: c#, regex, httpresponse

I'm getting web response and trying to find ID in it.
I wrote :

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)(?=\) title=)");
return regex.Match(readStream.ToString()).ToString(); //suppose there is a problem
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It would help if you gave us the content of `readStream.ToString()`, it's probably not what you think it is.

Comment: `readStream.ToString()` will return `System.IO.StreamReader` - not the contents of the stream. Try using `readStream.ReadToEnd()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readStream.ToString` is supposed to return something like `System.Object.StreamReader` since it's default realization of this method.

Try to use `readStream.ReadToEnd()` instead.